# GLKViewController - DrawinRect and Update stop firing when leaving view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0, glkit, glkview

I've a `GLKViewController` which renders an OpenGL 2.0 scene. All works fine, but when I segue to a new storyboard scene (via a UINav Controller) and then return to the OpenGL ES 2.0 scene, the `update` and `drawRect` methods in the view controller are no longer called.

I've tried setting self.paused to NO in the `viewDidLoad` method, but to no avail.

Can anyone suggest what is happening here ?

The GLKViewController contains a UIView, both of which are set in the storyboard. This is the segue to the view from the GLKViewController :

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GoToEntry"]) {

    DetailViewController *d = segue.destinationViewController;
    d.selection = currentSelection;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - the problem was that GLKViewController sets paused to YES when view exits. viewWillAppear wasn't actually being called - moving self.paused to viewDidAppear solved the problem.